# Why is it not giving me a badge?

Tags: bug, badges

I know this isn't a game, but, this has been there for like, 3-4 months, here's an image:[image]

Comment: "I know this isn't a game" — [but it is 'gamified'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification). StackExchange (SE) does _a lot of things_ to "increase our engagement", to the extent where it effectively becomes addiction. Really, addiction like in nicotine, coffeine, gambling, social media, etc. addiction. With all of its dangerous effects. But it seems without triggering addiction in users, the SE model could not work, or could work far worse. The entire SE concept needs a lot of people to regularly participate. Addiction is a tool to keep bringing people back every day.

Comment: weirdest game ever-but nice

Comment: @Joachim I think the badges, and rep points, and competition for the rank do make it a game... Also, watch out for Fixer123, he's catching up to you!

Comment: @Isaac750 That's a matter of perspective. If one wants to have the highest score, and think that makes one the 'best', then sure, it's a (one-sided) game. But it doesn't reflect who is the 'best user' at all: it doesn't reflect the quality of questions and answers, the support someone gives to other users, the correctness of contributions - it is merely a vague indication of the amount of interactions, which is still subject to what's popular and what's easy to digest.

Comment: one question... Is this soon gonna be fixed? or is it just not 'important' idk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Because you haven't maintained the 'positive question record' the badge requires** (see [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users/10115/isaac750?tab=questions&sort=newest)).

Clicking on the badge actually informs you of this ("need positive question record"):

[image: "Need positive question record"]

What constitutes a positive question record is [the following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290545/how-is-a-positive-question-record-calculated):

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5

Which gives you a score of (19 - 6 - 6)/19 ≈ 0.37

**So you need three more positive questions (and no negatively received ones), and you will receive the badge.**

---

It is a little strange that the counter does not take that sequence into account, however, but [this issue has already been raised on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251172/should-we-change-the-positive-asking-record-criteria-for-the-curious-badge-set).

Comment: Is that a screenshot of my profile? wut? How'd u get there?

Comment: @Isaac750 Yup. Almost everything here is open and transparent. Clicking any other profile will give you insights into another user's activity.

Comment: but u can't see: "following", "Bouties", "Reputation", or "all"

Comment: @Isaac750 Maybe you need more reputation for that.

Comment: maybe? Joachim, you have over 6k rep... "maybe" I need some more rep